Why can't I add an NUnit test project to my solution?
I have two solutions: an application and a shared library. The application solution includes an NUnit test project that works fine. However, if I create an NUnit test project in my shared library solution and copy and paste the working files, it throws crazy errors:

I verified that both solutions have the same package versions but they mysteriously don't work inside my shared library. Both solutions are .net core 8.0. I can't find any information on the "Not available" error. What do I need to do to be able to use NUnit?

I'm a little confused by your terminology/description. You don't install packages in a solution, you install them in the projects. What is installed in the project where you have this test class?
